# How to bind an unbound value in a List in Oz

Tags: oz, mozart

Let's say we have the following code:

```
local L in
    L = {List.make 10 $}
    % Bind nth element to something here
end
```

How does one set any of these unbound values? The [Oz List Documentation](https://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/base/list.html) didn't shed any light on this. The only related question I found was: [How do you change an element in a list in Oz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194783/how-do-you-change-an-element-in-a-list-in-oz) where the answer didn't compile for me, nor did I find how I could get it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to use something from the [Oz List Documentation](https://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/base/list.html) to get it to work!

```
declare Temp Index Value L in
L = {List.make 10 $}

Index = %Index to be bound
Value = %Value for bound

Temp = {List.mapInd L 
   fun {$ I B}
      if I == Index then
         B = Value 
      else
         B
      end
   end
$}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also just do `{Nth L Index} = Value`.

Comment: @wmeyer What the hell! :p I tried this but it failed, that's why I eventually went with this crazy implementation.. Must have made a mistake somewhere else in the code.. THANKS FOR THE TIP :D!

Answer (score 0):

wmeyer is right, the complete implementation could be for example:

```
declare
local L I V in
   L = {List.make 10}
   I=5 %index to be bound
   V=1 %value for bound
   {List.nth L I}=V
   {Browse L} 
end
```

You'll get the correct output `[_ _ _ _ 1 _ _ _ _ _]`. You can also access en element directly, but is not a programmatically solution, as you may know every list is a cons (head|tail), so you can access the first element with L.1 the second with L.2.1 and so on..
Last thing, you have no need to put "$" in the second line as you are already assigning the result of the List.make to L.